# Find the value of p such that X wins with probability of 1/2

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider a badminton game where there is no deuce and the first player to score
four points wins the game. Suppose player X wins each point independently with probability p
and Y wins with probability q=1-p

Suppose that player Y won the first two points, so now Y needs 2 points to win and X still needs 4 points.

Find approximately the value of p such that X wins with probability 1/2 .

I have so far found the equation of X wins to be $p^4+4[p^4(1-p)]=1/2$
as X needs 4 points to win so $p^4$ with Y having 4 possible point sequences to gain an additional point.

But I'm now stuck with the previous equation of $5p^4-4p^5=1/2$ I'm not sure what to do next.

Is my equation wrong? If not, then can someone advise me on what to do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the question only said "Find *approximately*" – rightly so, since the quintic is not solvable with radicals.

Plugging into Wolfram Alpha or any other good CAS gives $p\approx0.686$.

Comment: Just saying, with hypergeometric functions there are apparently epic "closed" forms according to WA